# Using NORMALIZE_STRING inside of a UDF --> "VARIABLE ... IS NOT DEFINED OR NOT USABLE"

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, user-defined-functions, zos

I am trying to use `NORMALIZE_STRING` inside a stored function under DB2,:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo(INSTR VARCHAR(4000) CCSID UNICODE)
      RETURNS VARCHAR(4000) CCSID UNICODE

      READS SQL DATA
      APPLICATION ENCODING SCHEME UNICODE      
  BEGIN
     SET RESULT = NORMALIZE_STRING(INSTR, NFD);
     RETURN RESULT;
  END#
```

However, I can not pass the second argument to the function, as this results in an error:

```
VARIABLE NFD IS NOT DEFINED OR NOT USABLE. SQLCODE=-312, SQLSTATE=42618, DRIVER=4.13.111
```

Is there any way I can get this working?

Do I have to specify some kind of scope/namespace/... to make clear that I am not referring to a local variable named "NFD", but to some constant, instead? The same applies to `NFC`, `NFKC` and `NFKD`.
Or is there any way to pass this parameter using another value (an integer constant maybe)?

I am looking forward to your ideas!

Comment: What do you mean by "some constant"? Where is that "NFD" defined, and how does the DB2 compiler knows about that?

Comment: The documentation states that you should pass "NFD" (without quotations) to the function (it's build-in). I don't know exactly where it is defined. I can use this syntax outside of a stored function without any problems.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the link to the documentation you're referring to?

Comment: Which DB2 version are you using? Your RESULT variable looks suspicious, not being declared anywhere.

Comment: Missing declaration is a copy&paste error, sorry. DB2 version is 10 (on z/OS). Documentation link: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_bif_normalizestring.htm